# Should we consider iPad as a handheld/mobile device , when we make website for smartphones?

Tags: css, ipad, xhtml, mobile-safari, mobile-website

Should we consider iPad as a hand-held/mobile device , when we make website for smart-phones like iphone, android, Blackberry, Windows Phone?

iPhone and iPad share same Operating system. So along with iPhone i should consider ipad also as a mobile device or I should consider iPad as a desktop/laptop device.

Comment: "Consider" in what context? When presenting an option to the user?

Comment: @Pekka - when we make website for smartphones

Comment: Don't make websites "for smartphones". Make websites for real use cases.

Comment: @David Dorward Visiting a website on a smartphone is a pretty common real use case these days.

Comment: It isn't the relevant bit. Look at the problem being solved (e.g. providing relevant train time information to people who are out and about and planning their route home) and solve that problem. The devices they are likely to be using come from the use case, they don't form the use case by themselves. Design solutions to problems, not sockets for tools.

Comment: @Quentin, I think you are a little off the mark here. Smartphones just don't support all the same input methods that standard browsers do, and therefore need to be taken into consideration specifically and separately.  You're obscuring the issue with a (dubious) point on symantics.

Answer (score 3):

Well, that depends. In general, I would say the iPad belongs in the laptop/desktop category. Most of the time, mobile sites are designed because of the small display-size or browser limitations on mobiles devices. The iPad has both a reasonable screen-size and capable browser.

However, when the site requires a lot of interaction with the user (like a web app or social site), I would prefer an interface that is a bit more kind to touch screens.

Alternatively, you could take a look at [responsive design](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/).

Comment: Just keep in mind that any click-and-drag mechanisms, like the ones provided by jQueryUI by default, will be totally unusable on the iPad.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your site, I would say. If the 'desktop' version of your site works OK on the iPad, and is easy to use, there is no reason not to use that one.

Comment: If my desktop version of website (960px width) working well on Desktop's Safari browser. than don't i need to worry about ipad compatibility?

Comment: I would certainly not say, in a blanket statement, that you shouldn't worry about it. You'll need to test your site in the desired browser on the device in question to know for sure. But if it works, and it easy to use for a mouse-less user, there's no reason you shouldn't have iPad users use the desktop version, as opposed to a scaled-down mobile version.

Answer (score 1):

I would say **not unless you are developing in flash** otherwise it falls into the category of netbooks IMHO, simply because of the larger screen real-estate.

Handhelds / mobiles are usually low resolution / small screen *'need to sacrifice'* devices.

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon the kind of webapp you're developing. A typical publishing site, for example, might be perfectly legible in the default layout for regular desktop computers. But since users visiting the site on iPad and tablets will be using their fingers to navigate, you may want to have a streamlined presentation that optimizes readability and makes navigation buttons and links a bit larger and easier to target by finger.

Also any touchscreen platform is not going to have use for a :hover state on links. This may have implications on your IxD if that kind of user feedback is important for regular platform users.

My approach currently is to use responsive design in a mobile-targeted front-end theme, that adapts use of screen real-estate depending upon resolution but still optimizes for the touchscreen experience.

Answer (score 0):

iPads tend to be used as a netbook / laptop replacement more than a mobile device, in my experience. Most sites work pretty well on them already. You should certainly check your sites on one, but barring the lack of Flash and smallish issues like the lack of a `onmouseover` event, there's little reason to develop an entirely separate site for them.